# Doing A Console Function and running a Tkinter GUI at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Let's say I want to send an email using smtplib AND have my text editor running. This is just one of the many things I am getting this error in, but this is a perfect example. The problem is this that the Text Editor Window freezes while the smtplib (representing "Console Function") is running. Any way I can fix this. This code shows this exact problem:

```
from tkinter import *

def sendMail(event):
    email = "email@email.em"
    password = "donttellanyone"
    subject = "Subject"
    message = "Message"
    To = "friend@friendlyppl.fr"
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, to, ("Subject: " + subject + "\n\n" + message))

master = Tk()

textArea = Text()
textArea.pack()

master.bind_all("<m>", sendMail)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could look for "tkinter + threads" or "tkinter + async".

Comment: How about `master.bind("m", lambda e: threading.Thread(target=sendMail, daemon=True).start())` and remove `event` argument from `def sendMail(event)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib, threading

def sendMail(event):
    class Process(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        def run(self):
            email = "email@email.em"
            password = "donttellanyone"
            subject = "Subject"
            message = "Message"
            to = "friend@friendly.fr"
            server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
            server.ehlo()
            server.starttls()
            server.login(email, password)
            server.sendmail(email, to, ("Subject: " + subject + "\n\n" + message))

    Process().start()

master = Tk()

textArea = Text()
textArea.pack()

master.bind_all("<m>", sendMail)

master.mainloop()
```

But can anyone please make it more compact and then send it here?

Answer (score 0):

This is the most compact and working code:

```
from tkinter import *
import smtplib, threading

def sendMail(email, password, to, subject, message):
    print("Emailing...")
    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, to, ("Subject: " + subject + "\n\n" + message))
    print("Emailed!")

master = Tk()

textArea = Text()
textArea.pack()

master.bind_all("<m>", lambda m: threading.Thread(target=lambda:sendMail("email@email.em", "donttellanyone", "friend@friendly.fr", "Subject", "Message")).start())

master.mainloop()
```